# Table of Contents Issue

Tags: table-of-contents

First time poster here.
I am working on a table of contents and ran into a small problem.

I wanted to remove any bold-facing from the table of contents page. So that all headings and sub-headings appear in regular font. To do so, I used the following:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}

\let\LaTeXStandardTableOfContents\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\relax}%
\LaTeXStandardTableOfContents%
\endgroup%
}%
```

However, I want the actual title of the page that reads “Contents” to be bold like the rest of chapter titles.

Is there a solution for this?
Any thoughts would be appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You could use a package like `tocloft` or `tocbasic`.

Example using `tocloft`:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftpartpagefont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First part}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Example using `tocbasic`:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=0pt
]{tocline}{part}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\normalfont,
  pagenumberformat=\normalfont
]{tocline}{chapter,part}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First part}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```